# get latest modified time of a folder in azure data lake using abfss path

Tags: python, azure, file, azure-data-lake, mount-point

```
>>> os.stat("abfss://path")
FileNotFoundError: [Error 2] No such file or directory: 'abfss://path'
```

`os` package only works with mount points, but I'm not allowed to use mount points in my project, is there any other way to get the latest modified time of folder which is present in azure data lake storage

**Answer:**
This is how I finally did it. 
by using `DataLakeServiceClient` class

```
storage_account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format("https",account_name)
service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url=storage_account_url, credential=account_key)
directory_client = service_client.get_directory_client(container_name, directory_name)
directory_properties = directory_client.get_directory_properties()
last_modified_date = properties['last_modified']
```

Comment: Hi @Nikhil Reddy, are you trying this code in databricks or synapse?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula-MT in databricks

Comment: hi, you have solved this?

Comment: hey @veroneseComS, yes i did. i've modified my original question with the solution.